# How to insert PreferenceFragment into ViewPager with SDK 22?

Tags: android, sdk, android-viewpager, preferencefragment

I already have a `PreferenceFragment` and a `ViewPager` with several tabs. Now I want to combine them together. I mean I want the `PreferenceFragment` become a tab of `ViewPager`.

I know that the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` can be used. But it seems that it requires **SDK 23**. And the **compile SDK** of my project is **22**.

Anyone, please, help me!